# Query to find posts with an exact set of tags (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have the following three tables expressing a relationship where posts are given tags (a many-to-many relationship):

```
create table posts (id integer, content text, primary key (id));
create table tags (tag varchar(30), description text, primary key (tag));
create table post_tags (post_id integer, tag varchar(10),
    primary key (post_id, tag),
    foreign key (post_id) references posts (id),
    foreign key (tag) references tags (tag));
```

Now suppose I want to find all posts with exactly the tags {clever,interesting}, and no others.

Here is my failed attempt. It finds posts which have the tags {clever,interesting}, but it also finds posts with the tags {clever,interesting,annoying} or {clever,interesting,unethical}.

```
select t1.post_id from post_tags as t1
    inner join post_tags as t2 on t2.post_id=t1.post_id
    where t1.tag='clever' and t2.tag='interesting';
```

I'm open to any suggestions for changing the structure to make this operation easier. However, I want to avoid things like adding a comma-separated list of tags in the `posts` table.

Comment: `tags` doesn't contain `post_id`, which _should_ be an 'execution error', so is something else going on?  Also, 'interesting' contains 11 characters, which might be a problem for a `varchar(10)` - you should probably make `tag` another int-based field, and either use the 'description' field, or create a new (larger, unique) 'name' field.

Comment: How is `'interesting'` stored inside a `VARCHAR(10)` field?

Comment: What you need is [exact relational division with no remainder](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). As you are on MySQL I would actually investigate how `GROUP_CONCAT` performs for this.

Comment: @X-Zero: Oops. The `tags` in the select statement was supposed to be `post_tags`. Fixed. I'm leaving the other things as-is, since they don't really affect the answer to my underlying question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an exact relational division problem.

In SQL Server a [well performing](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/06/30/Relational-division.aspx) method (assuming unique constraint on `post_id,tag`) is

```
SELECT post_id
FROM   post_tags
GROUP  BY post_id
HAVING MIN(CASE
             WHEN Keyword IN ( 'clever', 'interesting' ) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) = 1
       AND SUM(CASE
                 WHEN Keyword IN ( 'clever', 'interesting' ) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
               END) = 2
```

So I wouldn't rule out the idea of using `GROUP_CONCAT` in the `HAVING` instead.

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Keyword ORDER BY Keyword) = 'clever,interesting'
```

Comment: This looks great. Thank you very much for the name of this problem.

Comment: I ended up going this route. The query runs in about ~0.8s using the GROUP_CONCAT method, which is probably good enough. If it becomes a problem, I'll go the easy way out and store the tags in a comma-separated format in the `posts` table.

Answer (score 2):

Should be able to do this use [`NOT EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html), e.g.,

```
select t1.post_id
from post_tags as t1
    inner join post_tags as t2 on t2.post_id = t1.post_id
where 
    t1.tag = 'clever' 
and t2.tag = 'interesting' 
and not exists (
    select *
    from post_tags t3
    where 
        t3.tag not in ('clever', 'interesting')
    and t3.post_id = t1.post_id
)
```

Comment: While that works perfectly, it's unfortunately just too slow. My `posts` table has ~80k entries and `tags` has ~8k.

Comment: Performance is never a reason to reject a good solution. The query looks correct, and looks as lean as possible. Maybe adding a PK and/or indexes on post_tags will help. BTW: ig0774 seems to have restructured the original query, since he fails to use the post_tabs table (which looks wrong).

Comment: @wildplasser: Good point. I'll re-evaluate this solution, keeping your PK/indexes suggestions in mind. His mistake with tags/post_tags was actually my mistake. I mixed them up in my original question, but I edited it now.